# How to read values from boxes like messagebox or any other?

Tags: c#

I have a form displaying some datagirdview and textboxes...But I need to read two more values from any box like messagebox or some dialogue boxes... is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: if you are the one showing a message box why do you need magic to read the text you have passed to the messagebox.Show ? please clarify your question :)

Comment: david, thanks...nothing magic, just I need to read and hide the box

Comment: what is the box? how do you show it?

Comment: This should be tagged as windows-forms. But still, it's not a clear question though.

Comment: It sounds like he wants to popup a messagebox or something then read back a value? Possibly which button was clicked or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which technology: Web, WPF, WinForms?

On WinForms you would design a new Form that you would display using `form.ShowDialog()`. You can design that form however you like and set the AcceptButton and CancelButton properties to automatically set the DialogResult. Provide some properties on the form that you can read from the calling form.

Comment: sorry for delay...my internet connection problem...

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague - can you perhaps show some code?

If you want to hide textbox you should be able to use:

TextBox.Hide();

It depends what you want to read from the textbox - is it strings, integer, etc.  If it is a string you could have something like the below in your code:

string mymessage;
mymessage = Textbox.Text;

Comment: sorry for delay...my internet connection problem...

Answer (score 1):

Let me know the situation you need to do this. Can you elaborate your question.

I let you check if the following make a part of the answer.

You may do like the following 
Case 1. Fill the form, click 'next', show your pop up message window. Read data then submit.

Case 2. If you use web pages, you may use accordian or like controls to hide a portion of the page. So embed the control of the pop up message box in the accordion control.

Comment: sorry for delay...my internet connection problem...